# How can I move a turtle to a patch with a probability?

Tags: netlogo

It is a pretty simple model so far. I want the walker to move to the patches, but not randomly how it is now but with a probability. In this case it is the list "priority" which describes the probability for each patch (used vehicle).

So my question: How can I implement the calculated priority to the move statement?

Here's the code:

```html
   
        breed [nodes node]
breed [walkers walker]
globals [
  cost 
  time 
  wellbeing 
  efficiency 
  vec1 
  vec2 
  vec3
  nodelist
 ; rain
]
walkers-own [
 Temp_best ;aim temp 
 capital ; capital for each timestep to invest in transportation
 adaptation
 location
 priority
 delta-priority
]  ;; holds a node
patches-own [
  ]
to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape nodes "circle"
  ;; create a random network
  create-nodes 1 [ set color white ]
  create-nodes 1 [ set color blue ] ;car
  create-nodes 1 [ set color yellow ] ;bike
  create-nodes 1 [ set color green ] ;public transportation
  ask node 0 [ create-link-with node 1 ]
  ask node 0 [ create-link-with node 2 ]
  ask node 0 [ create-link-with node 3 ]
  ;; lay it out so links are not overlapping
  repeat 500 [ layout ]
  ;; leave space around the edges
  ask nodes [ setxy 0.95 * xcor 0.95 * ycor ]
  ;; put some "walker" turtles on the network
  create-walkers 1 [
    set color red
    set location node 0  
    move-to location
  ]
  reset-ticks

  ask walkers [
    set capital 5
    set adaptation 0.1
    set wellbeing n-values 3 [0]
    set priority n-values 3 [0] ;sum of all must be 1
    set delta-priority n-values 3 [0] ;sum of all must be 0
    set efficiency n-values 3 [0]
    
  ]
  set cost [3.5 1 0.1]
  set time [0.3 0.6 0.7]
  set vec1 [0.7 0.7 0.7] ;if change one, than also the other --> sum must be 1
  set vec2 [0.3 0.3 0.3] ;
  set vec3 [1 1 1]

 ask walkers[
 output-print wellbeing
  ]

  
  
  set cost (map * cost vec1)
  set time (map * time vec2)
   ask walkers[
 output-print cost
  output-print  time
  ]
ask walkers [
    set wellbeing (map + cost time)
    set wellbeing (map / vec3 wellbeing) ;devided by 1 to have a high number for wellbeing
    set priority [0 0.1 0.9]
   ; set priority (map + priority delta-priority)
    if rain? [
  set priority replace-item 2 priority 0
      set priority replace-item 1 priority (1 - item 0 priority + item 2 priority)
]
  ]

   ask walkers[
 output-print wellbeing
    output-print priority
  ]

 ;set efficiency replace-item 1 efficiency (wellbeing 1 / )
  set efficiency (map / wellbeing cost)

  output-print efficiency
;end

;to calculate
;ask walker[
;set delta-priority replace-item 0 delta-priority ( adaptation * item 0 priority * ((item 0 wellbeing) -  ) - ((item 1 priority * item 1 wellbeing)+(item 2 priority * item 2 wellbeing)))
 ; set priority replace-item 0 priority (priority 0 + delta-priority 0)
  ;set priority replace-item 1 priority (priority 1 + delta-priority 1)
  ;set priority replace-item 2 priority (priority 2 + delta-priority 2)
 ; set priority (map + priority delta-priority)
  ;ifelse wellbeing 2 > wellbeing 1
   ; output-print delta-priority
;  ]
end

to layout
  layout-spring nodes links 0.5 2 1
end

to go
  ask links [ set thickness 0 ]
  ask walkers [
    let new-location one-of nodes ;i want to introduce the priority for each node
    ;one-of [link-neighbors] of location
    ;; change the thickness of the link I just crossed over
    ;ask [link-with new-location] of location [ set thickness 0.5 ]
    face new-location  ;; not strictly necessary, but improves the visuals a bit
    move-to new-location
    set location new-location
  ]
  tick
      ask nodes
      [show count walkers-here]
  
  
end
```

Comment: have you looked at the `rnd` extension? Without looking through your code, this sounds like a problem for the `rnd:weighted-one-of-list` primitive

Comment: I agree with @JenB ; however, rnd broke with the last update >.< What version of NetLogo are you using?

Comment: Thanks guys I will try it now. I am working with 6.0.1